# Deploying asp.net web form into SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, sharepoint-server, asp.net

I have developed an **asp.net web form** in Visual Studio 2012 with the code behind in vb.net. I need to deploy this form into SharePoint 2013, in a perfect world I would like to have this form implemented into a custom list so I can develop a workflow from my form. Can anyone provide me with any help on how to achieve this?

I have been looking for articles and any help and haven't had any luck yet...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint term you are trying to create an application page and deploy it into SharePoint.

For that follow this article

Steps involved are

1. Create a new SharePoint 2013 Project with Visual Studio 2012.
2. Next deploy it as a Farm solution.
3. Next add a new “Application Page” item in your project.
4. Next add a TextBox in your Application page.
5. Set it to some value in the Code behind.
6. Next Build and Deploy the Project by clicking Start button.
7. Once its deployed you can verify the application page in the 15 hive.Navigate to `“C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS”` location and look for the project folder.
8. Next open the application page in the browser to verify the deployment.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/27/create-an-application-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Will I then be able to create a workflow off of this form in visual studio 2012?

Comment: If its a simple workflow then use SharePoint Designer 2013. Else you can create the workflow using VS and deploy it as part of the solution.

Comment: Ok, will try and deploy the form as application page now, and let you know.

Comment: Where did it deploy to? I deployed it to the dev server.. but do not see it anywhere?

Comment: Read step #7.. in browser it can be accessed via `http://webappurl/_layout/projectfolder/filename.aspx`

Comment: I see the ASPX file in the folder it leads me to, but doesn't give me the option to open it in IE or any browser...

Comment: You should manually open the path in browser.. The URL format i placed in my previous comment...Read step #7.. in browser it can be accessed via `http://webappurl/_layouts/projectfolder/filename.aspx` check this [image](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/applictaionPage.jpg)

Comment: Ok, stand by...

Comment: I have received an error when I run the path... it is saying I have an issue with my web.config file, but I do not have a web.config file in my project... you know where this can be found?

Comment: Every web application has a configuration file. Check your sharepoint server c:\inetpub\wss\ path

Comment: I do not see it in that directory... Any other advice?

Comment: it doesn't like that I am putting OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpDownLstEnt_SelectedIndexChanged" in my drop down list tag.. any other way to do this?